# How do i copy a single file from my s3 bucket that has a space in its filename?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli, cp

I am trying to copy

```
Sam's iPhone-2341234123.json
```

from my s3 bucket.

I am using the following line

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucketname/Sam's iPhone-2341234123.json ../
```

which presents

```
>
```

This is occurring because of the apostrophe. 
How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: For space, Use single quotation marks (' ') in Linux, macOS, Unix, or PowerShell. Use double quotation marks (" ") in the Windows command prompt

Comment: aws s3 cp s3://bucketname/'*iPhone-2342342342.json' ../
results in :

fatal error: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Key "*iPhone-2342342342.json" does not exist

Comment: `aws s3 cp "s3://bucketname/Sam's iPhone-2341234123.json" ../`

Comment: I tried this and got this error:::::           fatal error: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Key "Sam's iPhone-2341234123.json*" does not exist

Comment: Why is there an `*` in there? And does the file really exist? Can you post the `aws s3 ls` on that bucket!